# Change Text in TextView Box when Button is pressed

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm fairly new to programming and I am learning to develop in Java and building Android applications.

I am trying to create a Dreidel game,  on my xml file, I have a button, an imageview, and a TextView (I will be working on keeping the score a little later, I can figure that out on my own easily enough I imagine).

But the objective is that when I push the button, a random number generator produces a number from 0-3,

If 0, I want the TextBox to display "You get nothing"
If 1, I want the TextBox to display something else
If 2, I want the TextBox to display something else
If 3, I want the TextBox to display something else

Here is the code.  When I run it in the Android Emulator, it starts up but nothing happens when I click the button

```
package com.secondtry;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button spinButton;
TextView display;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.widget34);
    spinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Random numGen = new Random();
            numGen.nextInt(4);
        if (numGen.nextInt() == 0)
        {   
        display.setText("You get nothing");
        }
        else if (numGen.nextInt() == 1)
        {   
        display.setText("You get half!");
        }
        else if (numGen.nextInt() == 2)
        { 
        display.setText("You get it all");
        }
        else if (numGen.nextInt() == 3)
        {
        display.setText("Chip in a coin");
    }       }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: mark as accepted or vote up the answers which onr you think helped you

Answer (score 0):

Use numGen.nextInt(4) instead of numGen.nextInt() in your condition. Grab its value inside a variable(say x) and use that value in every condition.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
 int ran = numGen.nextInt(4);
 switch (ran){
    case 0:
        display.setText("You get nothing");
        break;
    case 1:
        display.setText("You get half!");
        break;
    case 2:
        display.setText("You get it all");
        break;
    case 3:
        display.setText("Chip in a coin");
        break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either define your button in onCreate with something like

```
final Button spinButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spinbuttonIdInXML);
```

Or pull the onClick outside of the onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your Button in OnCreate Like this..

```
spinButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.urbuttonid);
```

Answer (score 0):

updated try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button spinButton;
TextView display;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    spinButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonId);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.widget34);
    spinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Random numGen = new Random();
            int rNumber = numGen.nextInt(4);
        if (rNumber  == 0)
        {   
        display.setText("You get nothing");
        }
        else if (rNumber  == 1)
        {   
        display.setText("You get half!");
        }
        else if (rNumber  == 2)
        { 
        display.setText("You get it all");
        }
        else if (rNumber  == 3)
        {
        display.setText("Chip in a coin");
    }       }
    });
}
}
```